# Recreate a deployment without service outage

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-deployment

In the following scenario of creating a new deployment:

`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

```
/Mugen$ kubectl get deploy
NAME        DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
my-server   1         1         1            1           1h
```

I'm changing my `yaml` and running `apply` again and am getting a message that the deployment was updated.

But then I see two pods for my deployment and an indication that there are two instances, while only one is up to date.

```
/Mugen$ kubectl get deploy
NAME           DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
mysql-server   1         2         1            2           1h
```

From my understanding, if I would have used `kubectl replace --force` I would practically delete the current deployment and create a new one.

However, that will cause a service outage.

Is there a proper way to create a new deployment and delete the previous one only after successful rollout?

Comment: Your example is not clear, can you clarify it and also post the deployment.yaml. Are you only changing the `replicas:` ?

Comment: If you wait, the new pod should come up and once it passes its health checks, the old one should get torn down.  The default behavior for the command sequence you show should be what you want.

Comment: please provide `deployment.yaml` file and what was edited? As mentioned kubectl apply should work like you specified.

Comment: You are right, I need to work on my example better, for now I'm voting to delete this question and I will open a new one if needed when I can define it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracefully drain all pods (and then delete pods) and keep on adding new pods with new features.

Note that in production setups, recreate as deployment strategy is not advisable as this may lead to blackouts and service outages. Alternatively, you may want to also read more about different deployment strategies such as Canary Release (also read about Blue/Green) and/or RollingUpdate for production management.